# How do tell whenever to log with timestamps?

Tags: ruby, logging, whenever

The wiki article [Output redirection aka logging your cron jobs](https://github.com/javan/whenever/wiki/Output-redirection-aka-logging-your-cron-jobs) describes how to log when using whenever, for different environments, different types (STDERR vs. STDOUT) but there is no mention of how to log with timestamps.

Is there a way to add timestamps to the log when using whenever?

Answer (score 0):

To have environment in log path

> schedule.rb

```
set :output, { standard: "#{@environment}/log/whenever.log", error: "#{@environment}/log/whenever_error.log" }
```

For timestamp inside log:

Whenever simply outputs the exact output of the script file to log. So add timestamp in every print inside script file

> puts Time.now